# Upload File in MVC and create a link to Download the the file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, user-interface, file-upload

I have created this code for upload file. But it does not upload any file in the App_Data/Uploads folder i have created.
Here is the code>>

```
In view>>

<form action="~/Views/Home/_SaveUpdate" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

  <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

  <input type="submit"  />
</form>

And this my Handler>>

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Please tell me what more needs to be done. Also, how to generate the Link to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

First, the action of the form now points to `~/Views/Home/_SaveUpdate` while this should be `/Home/Index` based on your post-Action.
Second, make sure that you have created an Upload folder inside your App_Data folder.
This should take care of the upload problem.

View:

```
<form action="/Home/Index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
    <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
    <input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

If you want to display download links to all uploaded files, you should store the images in a different folder than App_Data. The App_Data folder is not directly accessible due to security reasons.

A good example to show the files in a directory can be found [here](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/689_Uploading_and_Displaying_Files_Using_ASP_NET_MVC_Framework.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and made just a few changes to test it.. and it worked.

For my tests i just changed the name of the action.
Are you sure your form Action is correct?

```
<form action="~/Views/Home/_SaveUpdate"
```

because it doesn't match with the name of your handler:

```
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable ....
```

My test:
Make sure your Upload folder exist or you'll get an exception.
The Handler:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUploadPost(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The View:

```
 <form action="FileUploadPost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label for="file1">Filename1:</label>
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

        <label for="file2">Filename2:</label>
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```